# Simple Heap Implementation - Custom Memory Manager

Tags: operating-system, heap-memory

I am currently taking an Operating Systems course and will have my first exam tomorrow. The professor has provided us with a list of topics to be prepared for and one of them is:

> Simple Heap Implementation

Based on the course material so far, I have an idea of what this entails but was wondering if anyone can possibly elaborate on this or direct me to some further resources to continue studying the topic.

What are some things I should be aware of and how can I go about implementing them?

Thanks

Comment: In what language you are asked to implement heap?

Comment: We are currently using BCPL but I'm not sure if he would like for us to program it or just describe the parts that make it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own memory manager using the data structure [**linked list**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).  Heap is used for dynamic memory allocation. For example: `malloc` in C allocates memory from Heap.

In a Dynamic storage allocation model , memory is made up of series of variable sized blocks. Some are `allocated` and some are `free`. So you will basically create linked lists`( to be specific doubly linked lists )`, for `free` memory blocks and `allocated` memory blocks.

Take look at [this](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs2604/fall04/docs/memman.pdf) and [this](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp00/cse120_A/mem.html) links for details. I suggest you better have a good understanding of the data structure `linked list` before doing anything else.

Comment: This is great. What book are you referring to here?

Comment: @User5842 Well, The book I followed in my college days was Data structures by horowitz and sahni. But the links are not related to the book. I just searched online and provided you with the links.

Comment: @User5842 But the content is more or less the same.